# cannot set inner class's private field using java reflect

Tags: reflection, mockito

i want to modify a private field of a class, say class A, which is a inner class of another class say class B. i tried java reflect package and can get that private field, but when i assign it to the mock object it complained it cannot set that field to the right class

here is my code:

```
public class Aggregator {
 public static class AMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text> {
    private LookupService lookupService = null;  <-- field to mock
    ...
  }
}
```

my test code:

```
aggregator = new Aggregator();
for (Class<?> c: aggregator.getClass().getClasses()) {
     if (c.getName().equals("Aggregator$AMapper")) {
         Field field = c.getDecalredField("lookupService");
         field.setAccessible(true);
         field.set(c, Mocito.mock(LookupService.class));  <-- failed here
         break;
     }
 }
```

the error message i got is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.maxmind.geoip.LookupService field Aggregator$EventTypeMapper.lookupService to java.lang.Class..
```

i cannot see what's wrong with my steps, anyone can help? thanks.

Comment: The idea is you inject the implementation into the class through it's constructor or a property. Then when testing you inject a mock instead. So is there some really good reason why you are hacking it like this?

Comment: The first argument to `field.set` has to be the object whose field you want to set, not some class.

Comment: the reason i need to do this is because that lookup service took too much memory and throw out of heap message, so i want to mock it in the test.

Comment: @David, the Mapper is a public static class inside Aggregator, i can only get it as class..

Comment: There still must be an object of that class.  Saying that it's a static class inside Aggregator just means that an object of that class doesn't have any dependency on an `Aggregator` object.  At some point, you have created an `Aggregator.AMapper` object; and that is the object you must pass to `field.set`.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to Java API doc [Field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) . I think code should be:

```
field.set(null, Mocito.mock(LookupService.class));
```